# SIGSEGV Segmentation fault, different message

Tags: c, gcc, gdb, buffer-overflow, segmentation-fault

I am trying to run the program to test buffer overflow, but when program crashes it shows me SIGSEGV error as follows:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   0x00000000004006c0 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffde78)

But the tutorial which I am following is getting the below message:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. 0x41414141 in ??
>   ()

Due to this I am not able to get the exact memory location of buffer overflow.

I have already used `-fno-stack-protector` while compiling my program. because before this I was getting SIGABRT error.

Does anyone have any clue so that i can get in sync with the tutorial.

Comment: Think about the implications of _**undefined** behaviour_!

Comment: @Olaf Think about the fact that this question is about *what actually happens* and not *what should happen according to the C standard*!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8S0SqXIGv98

Comment: @immibis: No, it is about what **could** happen and that there is no use in expecting  _**undefined** behaviour_ to behave a **defined** way. Nasal demons are always an option.

Comment: Addresses are virtual and are not guaranteed to be exactly the same on different machines/OS versions, etc. Worst, there is some mechanism to counterstrike such attacks, for example : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization... Don't rely on values, at least be careful...

Comment: @Olaf The question asks about buffer overflows.  This is probably an attempt at exploiting a deliberately vulnerable program. As we all know, the C standard does not specify a way to exploit buffer overflows, so the question is obviously outside the scope of the C standard.

Comment: @immibis: The question clearly asks why UB does not behave in a specific, i.e. defined way, which is an oxymoron. Therefore, the question even lacks a basis.

Comment: @Olaf If someone asked a question about vtables in C++, would you respond by saying that the standard doesn't contemplate anything called a vtable? Or would you assume they're talking about the implementation details of some particular platform?

Comment: @immibis: Finally: There is no environment given, there is no code given, there are no further details given. Just the C tag. Just giving the compiler is unsufficient, as gcc can build for a plethora of targets. Only some actually support some kind of memory protection/virtual memory. As given, we have to assume the question is about C. And there are many other reasons the program can behave different. Compiler version, optimisation, etc. It is just useless to speculate or even try to compare to a given example.

Comment: @Olaf Well then a better response would be to ask "What compiler, version and target are you using?" instead of saying "anything could happen", wouldn't it? We both know that no version of gcc on any supported platform will produce nasal demons.

Comment: @immibis: You either don't know nasal demons or not many architectures. I wouldn't go that far.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96458/discussion-between-immibis-and-olaf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to figure out the difference in both.

Actually I was trying the same code on Ubuntu 64-bit on virtual box.
But then I tried installing Ubuntu 32-bit on virtual box, so now I am also getting the same message as what was coming in the tutorial.

Also another difference which I noticed in 64 bit and 32-bit OS is that when using 32 bit we can examine the stack using **$esp**  but in 64-bit machine we have to use **$rsp**

Answer (score 0):

`SIGSEGV` is the signal raised when your program attempts to access a memory location where it is not supposed to do. Two typical scenarios are:

- Deference a non-initialized pointer.
- Access an array out-of-bound.

Note, however, even in these two cases, there is no guarantee that `SIGSEGV` *always* happen. So don't expect that `SIGSEGV` message is always the same even with the same code.

Comment: you are right but do you see the difference of memory patterns in both messages which I have posted in my question.

Comment: you mean the virtual addresses are different?

Comment: right, how can I get the address same type pattern which comes in tutorial

Comment: There is no guarantee such accesses will be detected. Nor is the program reuqired (or likely will) behave in a specific/defined way.